# numerically integrating singular function in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am dealing with integration over a rather singular function (such is the case in physics when dealing with Green's functions, see the attached figure) in python. What I did was the usual integration method:

```
quad(green_function,-cutoff,cutoff)
```

[image: real and imaginary part of the typical green's function G(omega)]

And the numerical integration is quite unsatisfying. I wonder if there is a better method in python other than quad that deals with this singular integration nicely?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the blue line? What is the result?

Comment: You probably want to apply some kind of transformation (maybe Fourier?) to make your integrand more tractable. As a side note, you might find better luck with such questions on [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com) or [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com) since this site is more about general programming.

Comment: See also, for example, [a neat trick by subtracting off the singularity as demonstrated by John D. Cook](http://johndcook.com/blog/2012/02/21/care-and-treatment-of-singularities).  In any case, it will be a lot more helpful if you specify exactly what function you're trying to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. @CommuSoft: the blue and green lines are real and imaginary  parts of the green's function (or integrands). The results are difficult to interpret. Physicswise, green's function is a function of two variables: g(omega,x). Here I plotted g as a function of x for fixed omega. There is a certain physics argument that relates the real and imaginary part of g(omega) after integrating out x. The reason I find the numerical integration unsatisfying is that such a physics argument is violated .

Comment: Do you know *a priori* where the singular (or near singular) points are?  If so, take another look at `quad`'s docstring.  The argument `points` can be used to tell the function where the singular points are.

Comment: @Rain: do you have to perform integration using *Python*? Systems like *Octave* are in general way better in integrating functions numerically...